# Append an elements HTML into newly appended textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website designer and have gotten stuck at a little annoying problem. I made a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish here - http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/KqyaH

The code below grabs the html in my canvas, puts it in a textarea when query is added, and I can see that html when I click on the already added media query.

```
$(".list-of-media-queries").append("<div class='list-of-media-queries-container'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del-media-query'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a> <button>"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"px</button>"+ "<pre style='text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;'>"+ "@media all and (max-width:"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"px) { \n\n" + $(".dadammediaquery").val() +" }</pre>" +"</div><textarea class='"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"'>"+ $(".canves").html() +"</textarea>");
```

When a global style is added into `div.list-of-css-selectors` I append the following tags `Textarea`, `DIV`, `Anchor`, `Button`, and `Pre`.

Here's an example of what is appended

```
<textarea class="custom-css-sheet hide" style="cursor:text!important; width:100%; resize:vertical; border:0; border-radius:0; min-height:200px;" placeholder="Your Custom CSS is added here"></textarea><div class="list-of-css-selectors-container"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="del-global-css-style"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a> <button>body</button><pre style="text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;">body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 224, 97);}</pre>
</div>
```

Now this is what I'm trying to backup aka `the global/custom styles`. I have all that stored in a `div.list-of-css-selectors` so I updated my code (2nd seen below) to where I wanted that backed up to. Now the code inside of `div.list-of-css-selectors` is suppose to go into the newly added textbox that has the class of the media queries location upon add. However the code is not encased in the textarea. Here's what I get instead.

```
<textarea class="custom-css-sheet hide" style="cursor:text!important; width:100%; resize:vertical; border:0; border-radius:0; min-height:200px;" placeholder="Your Custom CSS is added here">
```

I'm not sure why it's reacting this way. If anybody can help it'd be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".list-of-media-queries").append("<div class='list-of-media-queries-container'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='del-media-query'><span class='fa fa-times'></span></a> <button>"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"px</button>"+ "<pre style='text-align:left; padding-top:5px; overflow:auto;'>"+ "@media all and (max-width:"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"px) { \n\n" + $(".dadammediaquery").val() +" }</pre>" +"</div><textarea class='"+ $(".cwidth").val() +"'>"+ $(".list-of-css-selectors").html() +"</textarea>");
```

Comment: append the textarea and then use `val()` to set it's value

Comment: Lol idk why I didn't think of that. Works fine now.

Comment: @charlietfl should put that as an answer. Just Saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use val() to set textarea's  value

```
var string = "your html content";

var textarea=$('<textarea>').val( string).appendTo( containerSelector);
```